# reassign attributes in jquery without repetition of original value

Tags: jquery

I'm currently changing attributes of different elements using jQuery like:

```
// increase original value with 20%.
$('#view_port .scroll_container').width(1.2 * $('#view_port .scroll_container').width() );
```

or

```
// increase orignal value with 10 * padding value.
$('#view_port .scroll_container').width(10 * padding + $('#view_port .scroll_container').width() + 5 * padding);
```

In most programming languages I know I can do something like

```
width *= 1.2;
```

or

```
width += padding* 10;
```

Does jQuery/JavaScript offer similar constructs to easily change attribute values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.4.1, you can pass a function to [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2), which gets the current value as second argument:

```
$('#view_port .scroll_container').width(function(i, width) {
    return 1.2 * width;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest way to do that in jQuery is to pass a function to [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2):

```
$('#view_port .scroll_container').width(function(index, width) {
    return 1.2 * width;
});
```

Or:

```
$('#view_port .scroll_container').width(function(index, width) {
    return 10 * padding + width + 5 * padding;
});
```